# iTextSharp 5 Replace image to visible signature

Tags: c#, itext

I can get image from pdf file and replace it on other image using IndirectReference. Can i replace image on visible signature with simular way? If it not possible, how i can get correct image coordinates on sheet? using `image.GetTop(0); image.AbsolutePositionY` dont return correct coordinate.
I get image with this code :

```
 if (xobj != null)

        {

            foreach (PdfName name in xobj.Keys)

            {

                PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(name);

                if (obj.IsIndirect())

                {

                    PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj));

                    PdfName subtype = (PdfName)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)));

                    if (PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subtype))

                    {iTextSharp.text.Image maskImage2 = 
                    iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((PRIndirectReference)obj);
                }
          }
     }
```

Comment: You look at image resources but don't tell which resources. The image resources of signature visualizations usually are in the resources of the signature widget appearance stream or of Xobject used therein.

Comment: I get resources from last page of document. And i can get all images. My issue about how i can replace resulting image with a visible signature element, or get its(image) coordinates on the sheet

Comment: If you get the signature image from the document resources, then we are not talking about the visualization of a digital pdf signature but merely an ink signature image, correct?

Comment: Not exactly. The task is to replace a simple image with an interactive form with a certificate, just as it is done in this pdf [link](https://gofile.io/d/fKJlZv)

Comment: So you start with a PDF with a mere bitmap image of an ink signature and want to make it something like your linked PDF. Ok. In that case you indeed have to look at images directly or indirectly associated with the page contents. But you don't get the position and size of those images on the page by looking at the resources, you have to parse the content streams to determine where and how the images are drawn.

Comment: Related answers: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55236856/1729265) complete code of image extraction using the iText parser and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39392486/1729265) adaptions to an `IRenderListener` implementation to determine the current transformation matrix (CTM) at the time of drawing the image; you can read position and dimensions of the image on the page from the CTM. One word of warning, though: You will have to update your iTextSharp version to at least some 5.3.x'ish version, better to a current 5.5.x'ish one.